# convert and run docker-compose.yaml on kubernetes clusture?

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

I am using the following docker-compose.yaml file...

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: suji165475/vignesh:latest
    ports:
       - "3306:3306"

  tomcat:
    image: suji165475/vignesh:tomcatserver
    container_name: tomcat7hope
    links:
     - mysql
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
```

Running this with the docker-compose up command works just fine and I am able to see my app on the browser using https://serveripaddress:8080/data-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.

But now I want to deploy this on a kubernetes clusture.Therefore I converted the docker-compose.yaml file to kubernetes resources(deployments and services) using kompose convert and changed the spec type to NodePort in the tomcat.service yaml.

Currently I can only see the  tomcat hompage in browser with URL  https://serveripaddress:nodeport. But not my app using  https://serveripaddress:nodeport/data-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Do you see you app deployed on the K8S console? Everything you need to know to debug this is there.

Comment: iam getting a catalina lifecycle exception when trying to run the war file using tomcats manager app

Comment: i tried this using docker-compose and it works fine!!! but not in kubernetes

Comment: Maybe you want [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/)